# Sql not setting value on UPDATE

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql-update

I've been trying to update my orders table in my database using ajax. It seems as though my sql is not executing or there may be a problem with my syntax, I have checked and verified that the id variable I am passing through has been passed using POST and it successfully alerts when called upon in the javascript. The problem I am having is that my table is not updating.

my php here

```
if(isset($_POST['completed_id']) === true) {
    $comp_id = $_POST['completed_id'];
    include 'http://trecoolable.koding.io/res/res_php/conn.php';  //connection successful
      $sql = "UPDATE resorder_tb SET res_complete = 1 WHERE res_id =".$comp_id;  //not updating, checked and names are correct


      echo $comp_id;  //shows when echoed into my msg in javascript
}
```

javascript

```
        $("#compacc_but").click(function(){

            var completed_id = record_id;
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://trecoolable.koding.io/res/res_php/getOrder.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {completed_id:completed_id},    ///passing correct values               
            success: function(msg)
                        {
                            alert(msg); //alerting properly                                   
                        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you executing the $sql statement?

Comment: I realized that I haven't worked with UPDATE as much as SELECT so that may be the case, what would be the equivalent to something like $result = $conn->query($sql); that you would use for SELECT?

Comment: incredible -___- Thank you for reminding me that I have to execute queries before they actually work. Proper chuffed right now, you deserve a latte my friend

Comment: There is no need to fetch the result for an update query I believe. Other than that, $conn->query($sql) should work for all your sql queries. Assuming you are using a mysqli object.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code like below-

```
$sql = "UPDATE resorder_tb SET res_complete = 1 WHERE res_id =".$comp_id." "; 
mysql_qyery($sql);
```